# How does golang locate and download "sub-module" in direct mode?

Tags: go

I apologize for the excessive text, but I tried to explain how I think in detail.

Also, I know that term "sub-module" does not exist, since all modules are equal, but I am referring to a case where one module (go.mod file) is within some other module.

I am reading [documentation](https://go.dev/ref/mod) for golang modules and fully understand how it works in case of working through proxies, that is with GOPROXY protocol. However, I am confused by direct communication with VSCs (direct mode) when it comes to sub-modules.

Consider the following [alexedwards module](https://github.com/alexedwards/scs) and its [mysqlstore sub-module](https://github.com/alexedwards/scs/tree/master/mysqlstore).

Their module paths are:

1. alexedwards module -> `github.com/alexedwards/scs/v2` (`github.com/alexedwards/scs`)
2. mysqlstore sub-module -> `github.com/alexedwards/scs/mysqlstore`

First, documentation states the following:

> If the module path has a VCS qualifier (one of .bzr, .fossil, .git,
> .hg, .svn) at the end of a path component, the go command will use
> everything up to that path qualifier as the repository URL. For
> example, for the module example.com/foo.git/bar, the go command
> downloads the repository at example.com/foo.git using git, expecting
> to find the module in the bar subdirectory. The go command will guess the protocol to use based on the protocols supported by the version control tool.

However, since mysqlstore sub-module does not have VCS qualifier (its `github.com/alexedwards/scs/mysqlstore` and not `github.com/alexedwards/scs.git/mysqlstore`), we do not consider this.

Further, the documentation states the following:

> If the module path does not have a qualifier, the go command sends an
> HTTP GET request to a URL derived from the module path with a
> ?go-get=1 query string.

> The server must respond with an HTML document containing a  tag
> in the document’s .

So, I made a following [curl](https://reqbin.com/curl) request:

```
curl https://github.com/alexedwards/scs/mysqlstore?go-get=1
```

but got `404 (Not Found)`. Then, I was thinking maybe it works in the same way as in case of GOPROXY protocol and finding a module for package. Thus, I went a step back (took off `/mysqlstore`) and made the following request:

```
curl https://github.com/alexedwards/scs?go-get=1
```

and got the following meta tag:

```
<meta name="go-import" content="github.com/alexedwards/scs git https://github.com/alexedwards/scs.git">
```

So, according to this meta tag, it will now look at `https://github.com/alexedwards/scs.git` as repo-URL and `github.com/alexedwards/scs` as repository root path for the requested module `mysqlstore`.

Everything would be clear to me (at least I think) if there were no module (go.mod file) on a given path (`github.com/alexedwards/scs`), but there is. Will this way actually the wrong module being downloaded, that is, the `scs` module instead of the submodule `mysqlstore`? I mean, if `mysqlstore` is just a package, how can it even know that there is another module since we use `go get alexedwards/scs/mysqlstore` command for both package and module. In case of GOPROXY protocol it is solved by going backward (`.../scs/mysqlstore` -> `.../scs/` -> `...`), sending request for these paths and taking the module for longest path. However, in this case `https://github.com/alexedwards/scs/mysqlstore?go-get=1` did not gave a result.

I am missing something hard.

Does the module search process in direct mode really work as I described? Can anyone point me what I misunderstood and what the actual process is?

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you!!

Comment: “direct” has nothing to do with resolving the source of packages, they can all be located the same way without a proxy. Read https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths

Comment: @JimB I read it. Unfortunately, it does not provide any additional information to understand the case I described in the question. Actually the most of the text is the same as in the documentation I was reading and referring (https://go.dev/ref/mod#vcs-find) :(

Comment: @JimB The problem is that in the GOPROXY mode we are going backward and send request to proxy server. So we send request `.../scs/mysqlstore/@v/list`, then ` `.../scs/@v/list` then `.../@v/list` and we get either 404 or "content" response for all of them. At the end we take as the module root the one with longest path (in this case `.../scs/mysqlstore`). In "direct" mode, we would send requests `https://github.com/alexedwards/scs/mysqlstore?go-get=1`, `https://github.com/alexedwards/scs?go-get=1` etc. The problem here is that we won't get the response for first request like in case of proxy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

github.com is special, along with a few other sites. The go tool specifically knows how to fetch code from those sites. They are listed right at the beginning of https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Remote_import_paths

The workflow for locating source code repositories you describe only applies to other domains.

Comment: Thanks! Would be better if they more explicitly denoted it.